# Developing iPhone app on multiple Macs

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is probably super dumb, but can I use multiple Macs with different development profiles to make apps?  If I take my friend's Macbook on travel, who also is a developer and has his own development profile, can I use my own developer profile on it to work on my apps without interfering with his?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can, it's not about mac, it's your development profile which makes all the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share a single project on multiple Macs (each one having their own signing identity, or sharing the same Keychain items if they're both yours).

You can also use a single Mac to work with multiple signing identities.

I do both regurlarly as I'm enrolled in two companies that develop iOS apps; in both of them we're at least 2 developers having our own machines.

For your part, if you're borrowing a friend's Mac, I highly recommend to clone your Keychain's private key and certificates into this "new" Mac where you'll create a new user account, then delete this user account when you'll give it back.

Comment: And how could I do that signing identity sharing? Please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

For sure, as long as you install your provisioning profiles and emit new signing certificates.
I'm not aware of a way to export custom behaviors of other Xcode 4 configs, but that should not be a big problem.

After your trip is over, you can delete you provisioning profiles.

Comment: The last line made me laugh, not sure why. +1

Answer (score 0):

(Posting as another answer as it's not quite the same subject)

In any case, you'd better use some kind of source control such as Git (included with XCode) or Mercurial. Create a working copy of your project when you're off with your "roadwarrior" Mac, then merge when you come back.