# Allow multiple Macs to work on the same iOS project

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, certificate, push-notification

I need to know how to allow 2 Macs to work on the same project.

Currently the app is in the app-store and only 1 mac is working on the app.
I want to add a new developer, i.e. new mac, to the project.

Please provide me with a simple, step by step, instructions I need to do in order to make this work (regarding certificate, key-chain, bundle, etc).

P.S.The app uses push-notifications as well, does a new mac will damage the push notification mechanism?

I came across [Developing iPhone app on multiple Macs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846169/developing-iphone-app-on-multiple-macs), it didn't really answer my question. I want to know, from Apple perspective, what do I need to do in the new mac in order to build the exact same executable from both machines. (and not harm the current push mechanism).

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tool called version control. You could use git or SVN or Mercurial.

When compiling (with your company Apple Developer account) your code will be identical on both Mac (if you updated on both sides). Actually, my own code is indifferently compiled on my iMac, my Mac Book Air or my girlfriend's Mac Book Pro.

Comment: Hi, I have an "Individual developer program". What exactly do I need to do in order to import the certificate\private key\etc from the first mac to the second?

Comment: After I copy the certificate to the new mac should I do anything in the "iOS provisioning portal"??

Comment: Well, set it up exactly as you set up the first Mac: the core idea is, you want Apple to know that you're talking to them, not someone else :D

Comment: Thanks, do I need a new provisioning profile on top of the original certificate for the new mac?

Comment: I found a great resource for my question at the Apple provisining portal, under, certificates -> Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the 2nd Mac has the same iOS Development tools and SDK installed.  Export your Developer and Distribution certificates from the first Mac.  Create a new User account on the 2nd Mac and install the certificates there.  Copy your project and all source files ( including the app's plist, xibs, resources, etc.) to the 2nd Mac (or, if you are using a version control repository, check out a fresh copy of the desired revision).

Push notification have nothing to do with the Mac used for building an app.  If the 1st Mac is acting as the push notification server, it can still do so for apps built on the 2nd (as long as you don't change any IDs, etc.)

Comment: Hi, after I copy the certificate to the new mac should I do anything in the "iOS provisioning portal"??

Answer (score 0):

versioning :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

basically, you have a common box where to store your in-developement files (called "repository")

this repository has some features like version rollbacking, conflict and modifies tracking, bug tracking and so on...

the idea is simple: you have your files and your online repository, you add those files to your repo. i then join the project and grab those files (operation is called "checkout"), modify a bunch of them and i perform an operation called commit: this operation checks my version merge the modified files with the one online. You then "update" your local version: if you didn't modify the same lines i did, there's no error and you succesfully update. If we modified the same line, and there's conflict, the update process breaks. You can then see where the error appears, and resolve it with a diff tool (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)

Pretty easy as concept, pretty fundamental for us developer. You can have how many people working on the same project without problems. You can work on separate bits of code without the need of the other. You can work on the same file without generating conflicts.

[Google hosting](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/&rct=j&q=google%20code&ei=RGpnTvrIC4_LtAbqzanxCg&usg=AFQjCNFHgvJ0hYT3isyCVFQucmLRlUCw2Q&sig2=nxZtos7brQUVzOFghhEtrw&cad=rja) and [Sourceforge](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://sourceforge.net/&rct=j&q=sourceforge&ei=WGpnTu6vH8nHswbynJyCCw&usg=AFQjCNEqDlr0UDci2y2OqGHQcBP0Ri-unQ&sig2=fH1K3N3zxPMVNpBlEoWs1A&cad=rja) are two great example of repositories (you may also want to check out [Git](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://git-scm.com/&rct=j&q=git&ei=cmpnTrjGC4r2sgbhzK32Cg&usg=AFQjCNHBOAWIJWLQ6wmj_GErAgGzWCkTbA&sig2=5hBQhMXeepxh-IMFmBXi3w&cad=rja) which a little bit different)

so, briefly: SVN is the answer you need :)

Comment: SVN was the answer 10 years ago. ;-P